# Ошибка в моем коде jquery

Tags: jquery

Не могу найти ошибку в моем коде.Код должен добавлять всем ячейкам таблицы разный id.А добавляется всем одинаковый в чем проблема?

```
$('.price-table td').each(function(){
     var i = 0; i < 1000; i++;
    $(this).attr("id",+i);  
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Обратите внимание на параметры функции обратного вызова

https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$('.price-table td').each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).attr("id", "id_" + index);  
});
```

Можно без `each`:

```
$('.price-table td').attr("id", function(index, oldAttr) {
  return "id_" + index;
});
```

Что касается Вашего кода:

попробуйте объяснить самому себе, что в нем делает каждая строчка/функция/оператор.

Comment: можно без each.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('.price-table td').each(function(key, value){
        $(this).attr('id', key);  
});
```